# What does the FMT in FMTBcd stand for?

Tags: delphi

Delphi has a unit named `Data.FMTBcd.pas`.  (`FMTBcd.pas` in older versions).

I know that `BCD` stands for `Binary Coded Decimal`.

What does `FMT` stand for?

Comment: Perhaps it's FM followed by TBcd, where TBcd is the name of the type defined in the module.  But still I wonder, what does FM stand for?

Comment: Short for ForMaT.

Comment: TFMTBCDFiefd was introduced in Delphi6. TBCDField was already defined earlier, based on Currency type, with its limits, max 4 decimals, etc... So Borland was in position to invent a new class name, FMTBCD: ForMaT(ted)BCD with enough space to store numeric data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, `FMT` is a contraction of *format*.

Comment: Not to confuse with `function FormatBcd`.